# no se por que me da el error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa simple donde le pida al usuario los grados de los dias de la semana y me diga si esta templado, frio o caliente, de cada dia, y me sale el error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

codigo:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] dias = new double[7];
int i,a ;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        System.out.println("cual fue la temperatura del dia " + (i+1));
         dias[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    for(a=0; a<7; a++){
 if( dias[i] <= 0){
         System.out.println("dia lunes: Congelante");
 }else{
    if(dias[i] < 1 && dias[i] < 10){
         System.out.println("dia lunes: Muy Frio");
    }else{
    if(dias[i] >11 && dias[i] < 20){
         System.out.println("dia lunes:  Frio");        
    }else{
    if(dias[i] >21 && dias[i] < 24){
        System.out.println("dia lunes: Templado");
    }else{
    if(dias[i] >25 && dias[i] <29){
        System.out.println("dia lunes: Agradable");
    }else{
     if(dias[i] >30 && dias[i] < 35){
         System.out.println("dia lunes: Caliente");
     }else{
     if(dias[i] >36){
         System.out.println("dia lunes: Muy caliente, escapa de ahi¡");
     }
     }        
    }
    }
    }
    }
 }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en tu segundo for, donde estás utilizando la variable a, pero consultas por el vector dia[i].
Reemplaza

```
for(a=0; a<7; a++)
```

por

```
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
```

Y debería funcionar.
Saludos.